# ReferenceError: cptable not defined when running JEST test, error is in imported module and not in my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am getting "ReferenceError: cptable not defined" when running JEST test, error is in the imported module and not in my code. 
Module I am importing is a react component library and makes use of react-export-excel. All unit tests in imported react-component-library work fine and application also work fine. Problem is only with unit tests, getting below error.
        ReferenceError: cptable is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['ReferenceError: cptable is not defined' when running Jest tests, the actual code to generate the excel sheet works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181786/referenceerror-cptable-is-not-defined-when-running-jest-tests-the-actual-cod)