# 'ReferenceError: cptable is not defined' when running Jest tests, the actual code to generate the excel sheet works fine

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

The stack trace is as follows.

```
Test suite failed to run

ReferenceError: cptable is not defined

  1 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
> 2 | import ReactExport from 'react-export-excel';
    | ^

  at cptable (node_modules/react-export-excel/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:10:37)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-export-excel/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:6:1)
  at Object.require (node_modules/react-export-excel/dist/ExcelPlugin/components/ExcelFile.js:19:13)
  at Object.require (node_modules/react-export-excel/dist/index.js:7:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (components/CustomReport.jsx:2:1)
```

If i follow the trace, it reaches the following code section

at cptable (node_modules/react-export-excel/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:10:37)

```
if(typeof cptable === 'undefined') cptable = require('./dist/cpexcel');
```

I've seen github issues where they suggest to remove "use strict" from component code but I'm not even using it. Here is the related issue https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this library didn't help so went with another one.

> react-html-table-to-excel

Here, you need to create a html table and then that table gets converted to excel. I hid the table using CSS so that i only get the export excel button.